# Not having the permission to update menu path

Tags: 6, routes, users

I was trying to modify the path of the navigation menu link already created via `admin/build/menu-customize/navigation`.  I am getting the following error

[image]

When i try to create the new menu also i am geting the same error . any idea ?

I given the permission to `menu module` and enabled the `path module` too .

Comment: I hope you already know the answer to this question **[How to proceed with a D6 site after Feb 24, 2016 when D6 is end of life?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189569/how-to-proceed-with-a-d6-site-after-feb-24-2016-when-d6-is-end-of-life/189570#189570)**

Comment: This is a common drupal question isnt it ?

Comment: sort of, just wanted to make sure you knew. You got 2 weeks to upgrade to Drupal 7 or 8.

Comment: @NoSssweat : to access the link in your prior comment, +15K rep is required these days (try it ...). In case you ever look for an alternative, try [this link](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/98) instead ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thx, +10K rep actually.